# Position child views of relative layout in C# code in Xamarin.Native (specifically Android)

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm trying to dynamically add new views to an existing relative layout through C# code in Xamarin.Android. I haven't find any solution on how to position child views in the relative layout. Right now they are just placed at their default location in the top left corner of the application. I've seen solutions to this problem in Xamarin.Forms but not Xamarin.Native.

I have been able to specify width and height of the view through passing a ViewGroup.LayoutParams to the AddView method of the relative layout object, but there are no constructors etc of that class that handle position.

```
var root = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.relativeLayout1);

var tv = new TextView(this);

root.AddView(tv, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent));
```

I want to be able to use "layout_below" on the tv view through C# and not statically through AXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a rule to the layout parameters using AddRule() to place the view below the other one.  Here is an example I put together that adds two TextViews, with the  first being placed at the top (using .AlignTop) and the 2nd being placed below the first (using .Below).

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this) {Id = View.GenerateViewId(), Text = "TextView #1"};
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
    parms1.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignTop);
    tv1.LayoutParameters = parms1;
    rl.AddView(tv1);

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this) {Id = View.GenerateViewId(), Text = "TextView #2"};
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
    parms2.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, tv1.Id);
    tv2.LayoutParameters = parms2;
    rl.AddView(tv2);

    SetContentView(rl);
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]